# Using clevertap-react-native npm package, iOS push notification not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, clevertap

We are using:

- react-native - 0.51.0 and
- clevertap-react-native - 0.2.1

Here `https://www.npmjs.com/package/clevertap-react-native` we followed all the instructions and SDK integration steps for ios.

Also added `Clevertap.registerForPush();` in root file of project. But still Mobile push notification are not getting enabled in Clevertap Dashboard.

Here you can see, Mobile Push Notification in Clevertap Dashboard

[image: Dashboard]

Answer (score 3):

Can you verify once that you've enabled the support of the push notifications for your application?

You can check the same by following steps:

In Xcode, go to your Targets, under your app’s name, select Capabilities and find Push Notifications in the list, switch to ON

Helping Link: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devdfd3d04a1

Answer (score 0):

Hey this issue has resolved. There was firebase configuration code in my appDelegate.m because of that FCM token was getting generated.

After removing firebase code from AppDelegate.m; iOS push notification working.